# RXJS How do I load an array of images while successfully handling errors?

Tags: rxjs

I am looking to preload a bunch of images, and have discounted `base64` and `createObjectURL` so i'd take a better option, but this is what I have.

Anyway this is what I am looking at, a function which does this.  Loads an array of URLS as images.

```js
const urls = ["lol.jpg"];
const images = urls.map((url) => {
    const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    const imageComplete = fromEvent(imageElement, 'load');
    imageElement.src = targetURL;
    return imageComplete;
});
forkJoin(images)
```

But how do I correctly handle loading errors here?  I have added a new `fromEvent` but now I have 2 events where I used to just have one, and further one of them is the `special error case`.

```js
const urls = ["lol.jpg"];
const images = urls.map((url) => {
    const imageElement = document.createElement('img');
    const imageComplete = fromEvent(imageElement, 'load');
    const imageError = fromEvent(imageElement, 'error');
    imageElement.src = targetURL;
    return imageComplete; // <--- not good enough now
});
forkJoin(images)
```

Is it correct to listen for an error here?  Ultimately I need to know if any of these fail and consider them all failures but during my tests, a 404 doesn't `catchError` anywhere and this brings me to this question.

Comment: Does `fromEvent(imageElement, 'error')` emit a value that you need to interpret as an error, or is RxJS clever enough to treat this event as an error in your stream? I'll clean up my answer below if you let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in part, depends on what `fromEvent(imageElement, 'error')` does here:

```
fromEvent(imageElement, 'error').subscribe({
  next: val => console.log("next: ", val),
  error: err => console.log("error:", err)
});
```

If you do this, and you receive an error, does the event trigger `next` or `error`? Either way, I assume you want to remove `imageElement` if it fails to load.

If it triggers `error`, then you can do this:

```
const imageComplete = fromEvent(imageElement, 'load');
const imageError = fromEvent(imageElement, 'error').pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    imageElement.remove();
    return throwError(err);
  })
);
imageElement.src = targetURL;
return merge(imageComplete, imageError);
```

If it triggers `next`, then you can switch imageError into a stream that errors out by throwing an error like this:

```
const imageComplete = fromEvent(imageElement, 'load');
const imageError = fromEvent(imageElement, 'error').pipe(
  tap(x => {
    imageElement.remove();
    throw(new Error(x.message));
  })
);
imageElement.src = targetURL;
return merge(imageComplete, imageError);
```

Now, `forkJoin` will fail with your error if any of its sources fail. If you don't want that, you need to handle the error before it reaches your forkJoin.

---

#### Retry failed images a few times instead

The trickiest bit here is that you need to create an image element as part of your stream so that when you re-try it will not just resubscribe to an event of an already failed element.

The other tricky bit is that you want to create your imageElement as part of subscribing to your stream rather than as part of its definition. That's what `defer` essentially accomplishes for you.

With that out of the way, not many changes, and you can re-try loading your image pretty simply. You can read up on `retryWhen` if you want to make the process a bit more sophisticated (Like delay a bit before retrying).

```
const images = urls.map(targetURL =>
  defer(() => of(document.createElement('img'))).pipe(
    mergeMap(imageElement => {
      const imageComplete = fromEvent(imageElement, 'load');
      const imageError = fromEvent(imageElement, 'error').pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          imageElement.remove();
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
      imageElement.src = targetURL;
      return merge(imageComplete, imageError);
    }),
    retry(5),
    catchError(err => {
      console.log(`Failed to load img (${targetURL}) 5 times`);
      // Throw error if you want forkJoin to fail, emit anything else
      // if you want only this image to fail and the rest to keep going
      return of(new DummyImage());
    })
  )
);
forkJoin(images);
```

In this case, since we've dealt with errors before they hit the `forkJoin`, we can expect the array of images to contain a `DummyImage` anywhere that an image failed to load 5 times. You can make `DummyImage` anything, really. Have a low-res default img loaded locally, for example.

If you `return throwError(err)` instead, then the entire `forkJoin` will fail the moment any image fails to load 5 times (It'll still retry 5 times though) and you'll not get **any** images. That might be what you want?